# Should a step by step solution be a requirement for some genres of puzzles?

Tags: discussion

For some puzzles, such as Sudokus or nonograms, posting the answer is not enough. Doing so results in requests for a step by step solution, but this isn't actually a requirement.

I'm thinking maybe it should be a requirement for grid like puzzles. Here are some reasons why:

- It proves you didn't just put it into an online solver
- It helps others learn where they went wrong or how to solve such puzzles
- Makes it easier to identify possible errors

However there are some reasons why people might not want this to be a requirement:

- It is time consuming
- You've already solved the puzzle, so shouldn't be made to have to explain how

We have a similar requirement for riddles, where you have to explain why, but

**Should step by step explanations be required for these genres of puzzles?**

Comment: Good question! I personally always try to do this, but I'm also happy to upvote (correct) answers that don't. Could go either way on whether to make it a requirement, really.

Comment: To add, a step-by-step solution is not that helpful in many cases. Either the reader got bored and just wanted to see the solution, then got intimidated by a wall of text and left, or the reader got stuck in the middle of the puzzle, but found that a different approach was used in the solution. This doesn't always happen, but I'd imagine that this happens frequently.

Answer (score 2):

**Personal work-around**

*Personally*, I put up my final solution with a comment along the lines of 'I will add a step-by-step later' and later when I have time, I actually add my method. This is for two reasons:

- Most of the time when I find a solution I don't have time to write up a method
- (Okay, I'll admit it) I don't want to get ninja'd by somebody else :)

**So should we require a method?**

For me it depends on the difficulty of the puzzle. For example in the puzzle  [WITLESS - A Puzzling Journey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47870/witless-a-puzzling-journey), the inscriptions and constellations shouldn't require a step-by-step but the final (well, really, *biggest*) puzzle should. I mean, for any puzzle, if the whole puzzle is one big grid-deduction then I would recommend adding a step-by-step solution. In the case of a few (or a lot!) of small puzzles probably not. So my vote is **yes** a method is required.

**But I guess-and-checked...**

If guess and check is used, then just mention your *thought process*. For example if you have an instinct that *this square must be part of this region* then say that.

So in summary as long as your solution **makes it clear to other users how you arrived at a solution** then it seems reasonable to me.